# Where can I find the exchange 2013 logs specifically for denied impersonation attempts?

Tags: active-directory, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013

I have a windows box with AD & Exchange 2013 on it. There are around **400 users** with mailboxes. One user (`ServiceAdmin`) had been given impersonation rights over a group and then the rest of the users are added to the group, essentially providing scope impersonation rights to the `ServiceAdmin` over all the users in the group.
Now if, for some reason, the user is disabled/removed in the AD, and an attempt to send mail through impersonation is made, the impersonation request is rejected with **`<e:ResponseCode>ErrorImpersonateUserDenied</ResponseCode>`**.

**Question is**, where is this event logged on the exchange host?

Tried hunting on Google and MSDN. They all end up validating one configuration or other at a time. Problem is, that for a operation (as mentioned above) to work, multiple points of configuration have to be right. So I'm looking for a way to either diagnose beforehand all the users for which it will fail or a log from where all the users,  for whom impersonation has failed, can be extracted.

Will appreciate any help in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

EWS requests will be logged in the EWS Log on the CAS server eg https://ingogegenwarth.wordpress.com/2017/01/12/troubleshooting-exchange-with-logparser-ews-logs/

> > Tried hunting on Google and MSDN. They all end up validating one configuration or other at a time.

Its sounds like you already have your answer there are no shortcuts to this if something fails it could be one or many reasons hence why you need a step by step verification to find the actual fault and then resolve it (or suggest a resolution). There are no shortcuts to this and even with a step by step verification you can still come across specific customer environment differences that invalidates that.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. :-) 
I agree that the actual problem has to resolved in a step by step manner. However, the attempt of mine is to identify all the accounts that are facing a problem of denial for impersonation (due to one reason or other), even before they are reported.

Comment: If you know the reason they are failing then you write a check using the appropriate API for that reason. If you then come across that error in you code you should be able to branch to fix.

Comment: So, there are 3 time windows here, 1) before the event, 2) between event & user ticket and, 3) after user raises a ticket. I need to identify the users, who have already failed ( _& possibly been added in the AD/Exchange logs_ ) but before ticket i.e in the 2nd window. Essentially, a reactive identification with a minimal reaction time. Which log on the exchange/AD will capture this event?

Comment: The EWS log is the only thing that would be enabled by default and would capture the attempt and error . Mailbox Auditing if you turn it on should also capture any logon attempt it differs (improves) between versions. IMO logs are the wrong way to go about it, if you know the resolutions for the issue just scan the user configuration to pick the configuration inconsistency and fix them, the logs are more for use when something falls outside of the known fixes.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on EWS logs.
On the other approach you recommend, I'm not familiar with exchange administration and it's scripting. Are you suggesting a powershell script? If so, could you possibly share a template/sample to iterate over all the users in a specific group to check for their AD status (active/inactive/removed/etc.) and the impersonation rights over each one?